# Rejecting mapping update to [] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type

Tags: elasticsearch

I have create index with explicit mapping:

```
PUT http://192.168.1.71:9200/items
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": { 
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
            "num": {
          "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And trying to add document:

```
POST http://192.168.1.71:9200/items/1
{
  "num" : 1.898,
  "name" : "aaa"   
}
```

But get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [items] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, 1]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [items] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, 1]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Why and how can I fit it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the document type before the `id` which is `_doc`

```
POST http://192.168.1.71:9200/items/_doc/1
{
  "num" : 1.898,
  "name" : "aaa"   
}
```

Comment: Why only _doc? What in case if I want to use different one ?

Comment: @KapilRaghuwanshi you can use a different one only if you are using a elastic version lower than 7.0, however, it'll be a problem during an upgrade if you have multiple mapping types. Consider read this - [Removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)

Comment: @PolynomialProton so how can I use multiple doc types in ES 7.x?

Comment: @Volatil3 A different index per document type is what i'd do. Elastic also has some other recommendations here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_alternatives_to_mapping_types